# c++ use LoadLibrary to load winapi interfaces from dlls

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, interface, loadlibrary

How can I use this function to load winapi interfaces like ishelllink from dll , I already can load winapi functions properly without problems

Comment: `ishelllink` is a COM interface have a look in the DLL listed in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774950(v=vs.85).aspx  But probably easier just to use COM normally.  Also this: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040205-00/?p=40733

Comment: Difficult to know what you are asking here. Why can't you use these COM interfaces?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What problem are you _actually_ trying to resolve?

Comment: Are you trying to understand how `CoCreateInstance` works? Given that it (must) leverage `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress`?

Comment: You cannot load an interface from a DLL. You can load a server DLL, and request that its class factory constructs an interface implementation on your behalf. So as written, the question really doesn't make much sense, and is probably the result of failure to fully understand COM.

Answer (score 2):

[`IShellLink`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774950.aspx) is a COM interface. You don't use `LoadLibrary()` to access COM objects, you need to use [`CoCreateInstance()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686615.aspx) instead.  There is a code example in the [Using Shell Links](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776891.aspx#Shellink_Using) documentation on MSDN.

Comment: I know its a com interface and I already can use it but I only gave an example for the interfaces , I want to be able to get them dynamically during runtime

Comment: @prog511: If that is what you are trying to accomplish, you are going to have to re-invent the registry. And a substantial part of the COM infrastructure: [CoGetClassObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684007.aspx). That sounds a lot like you haven't quite understood COM yet. What are you *really* trying to accomplish here?

Comment: @prog511 "*I want to be able to get them dynamically during runtime*" - `CoCreateInstance()` **IS** how you get them dynamically at runtime

Comment: Ok, I now understood !